# MySQL python DBAPI. How to get a dictionary instead of a tuple?

Tags: python, mysql, python-db-api

Python DB API returns a list of tuples when fetchall is invoked on an executed cursor. If you work with the _mysql module, fetch_row has a `how` parameter that allows to get a dictionary instead of a tuple. How can I achieve the same with the cursor ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from [the documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html)

```
DictCursor
    Like Cursor except it returns rows as dictionaries.
```

Comment: Blindness is my friend, but google didn't help. Now it will. Thanks.